# Finding a match in two files and merging the data

Tags: python, pandas, file, merge, extract

**Input: file1**

```
0        1             
EXE    sldk  
EXE1   vkrk
TPO    dlfk
EXE2   sdfs
```

**Input: file2**

```
0               1
DD=CMD     asldkjfalsdkfj
DD=EXE     mbnwjnjcxjic
DD=DMFF    pklckwkflkdf
DD=EXE2    okvwokmvfv
DD=EXE1    ksdjfokwoekc
```

**Expected output: file1#**

```
0       1         2    
EXE    sldk     mbnwjnjcxjic
EXE1   vkrk     ksdjfokwoekc
TPO    dlfk     NaN
EXE2   sdfs     okvwokmvfv
```

**Result: file1#**

```
0       1         2    
EXE    "sldk"     "mbnwjnjcxjic"
EXE    "sldk"     "ksdjfokwoekc"
EXE    "sldk"     "okvwokmvfv"
EXE1   "vkrk"     "ksdjfokwoekc"
TPO    "dlfk"     "NaN"
EXE2   "sdfs"     "okvwokmvfv"
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open(file1, 'r') as file1, open(file2, 'r') as file1:
    lines_1 = file1.readlines()
    lines_2 = file2.readlines()
    lines_1_column = [x.split(',') for x in lines_1]
    lines_2_column = [y.split(',') for y in lines_2]

df_file1 = pd.DataFrame(lines_1_column)
df_file2 = pd.DataFrame(lines_2_column)

extract_from_two_files = file2[0].str.extract(f'({"|".join(file1[0])})', expand=False)

merge_two_files = file1.merge(file2[[1]], how='left', left_on=0, right_on=extract_from_two_files)
merge_two_files.columns = np.arange(len(merge_two_files.columns))

merge_two_files.to_csv(file 1#, index=False, sep=',', header=None)
```

I wanna get the 'Expected output: file1#', but the result is just like 'Result: file1#' with this code. I'm sorry but is there any suggestions you have?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary variable from `file2`, without the `DD=`, and merge data found in both DataFrames in the first column (`0`) using the `on` parameter.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', sep='\s+')

df_tmp = df2.replace('DD=','', regex=True)

result = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df_tmp, on=['0'], how='left')
result.columns = range(len(result.columns))
print(result)
```

Output from *result*

```py
      0     1             2
0   EXE  sldk  mbnwjnjcxjic
1  EXE1  vkrk  ksdjfokwoekc
2   TPO  dlfk           NaN
3  EXE2  sdfs    okvwokmvfv
```